# How to notify admin dashboard when user creates a new record (all internal)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webhooks

Say I have an admin dashboard page `/dashboard` that lists all `Orders`. I have a separate page `/new` where an `Order` is created (upon submit, it posts to `orders#create` action), and a `/confirmation` page that is where a user is sent once an order is created. The controller structure looks like this:

```
class AdminsController
    def dashboard
        @orders = Order.all
    end
end

class OrdersController
    def new
    end

    def create
       redirect_to "/confirm"
    end

    def confirm
    end
end
```

I'd like the dashboard page to display something (let's say, for ease, an alert) whenever a new order is successfully created. My first thought is to implement an internal webhook (i.e., it's not like the new order is being created on a 3rd party platform that I then have to listen for, but my own server), but I'm new to webhooks period so want help with this.

My initial thinking is, with lots of pseudo-code.

1) Create a new method `add_to_dashboard` in `AdminsController` that functions as the consuming method.

```
def add_to_dashboard
  begin
    event = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
    render # a js.erb file of some kind
  rescue
  end
end
```

2) The `js.erb` file that is rendered will then update the `/dashboard` page

```
.js.erb file
alert("new order created")
$("#orders").append("<%= @order.id %>")
```

Is the above an appropriate way of consuming the data after a new order is created? If so, then onto the production side, which is where I'm kind of lost... I don't understand where to call the `admins#add_to_dashboard` action from. It's against Rails convention to POST internally to another controller action so... how does the `add_to_dashboard` happen?

Comment: https://gorails.com/episodes/in-app-navbar-notifications?autoplay=1 please refer this video tutorial, its pretty simple

Comment: you can use actioncable for realtime notification

Comment: @AbhishekAravindan thank you, FYI though, the in-app notifications in that video are not dynamic, they reload on page refresh only